# Text message via SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have some to critical jobs in our production system. We receiving email about of job status succeded or failed and also we want to set send text message from SQL Server. I searched but looks not so possible, has anybody tried before ?

Comment: What kind of text messages do you want to recieve from SQL server? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you can only do this using third party tools.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql

Comment: I need to send normal text message. I need something like procedure. In GUI its not any tool for Text Message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this a long time ago using a third-party tool that offers exactly what you need. You can find out more about it [here](https://www.activexperts.com/sms-messaging-server/).
And [here](https://www.activexperts.com/files/sms-messaging-server/manual.htm#Send_and_Receive) you can find detailed information on how to send and receive messages from `SQL Server`, using this tool.

*In the website it is stated that you can only use this for free for the first 30 days.*

Basically you will need to host their small database on your `SQL Server` and then insert a row into a `Messages` table with the message you want to send along with the phone number to which it has to be delivered.

*"The SMS Messaging Server service application will pickup any newly added messages and send them out through the appropriate channel automatically."* as stated in the documentation.

[image]

However, because it is a third party tool and not open source, I don't know if it will be suitable for you. I am not aware of any free tools for the same purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this link where it is explained how to turn emails into text messages, it has an inconvenient, however: you have to know the cellular provider for each of the phones you want to send message.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2922/sql-server-alerts-with-text-messaging-from-sql-server-database-mail/

Best regards,

Comment: I saw this link but i dont know providers. Thx.