# A way to send a Microsoft Teams chat message from SSIS

Tags: ssis, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to send an MS Teams chat message to one or more people or even to a Team Post from SSIS?

We have some processes that send notices via Email, but anymore email is just too busy and it would be nice to have a central location in Teams to have messages when certain items complete or fail via SSIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are a few possible options for this. If you're sending email already, the most simple might be to just use the Team (i.e. Channel's) email address. To access this, go to the "..." menu next to the channel name, and select "get email address", as shown below.

[image]

A popup will appear showing the channel's email address.

[image]

Here's [a video](https://twitter.com/Microsoft365/status/1229797724880560129) showing this.

Another option is to set up an ["incoming webhook"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using). I've not done this in SSIS, but I think this would involve using a Script Task to call the endpoint that gets created.

Comment: Sam, was this able to help you?

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know this was a thing, but sure enough on the Team I need to post to I was able to get an email address and send a test to it.  I'll see if I can use this from SSIS as I am already sending an email within the same process.  I learned something new today.

Comment: great stuff - I hope this worked out in the end inside SSIS?

Answer (score -1):

Take help from following Link:
Following link help to send text message via sql server
[Text message via SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647511/text-message-via-sql-server)